# Can we record audio in PC (not Android) using wireless headsets (inbuilt mic)?

Tags: wireless, compatibility, headset, audio-recording, audio-quality

I would like to know whether we can record audio in PC (again, not Android) using wireless headsets(inbuilt mic) which use bluetooth for connectivity. I am casting doubt because I read that they can be used only for calls not for audio recording (not talking about call recording because it's confusing). Also, I would like to know the quality difference between the audio recorded in wired one vs wireless one. Moreover, are wireless headsets generally compatible with all BIG 3 OS:- Windows, Android and iOS ?

Comment: Personally I've used the software "Audacity" in the past to record sound from a microphone. I assume that should also work with wireless headphones, though the ones I used were wired.

Wireless bluetooth headsets should be compatible with all operating system. My wireless headset and headphones work perfectly with both Windows and Android. I don't have an iOS device to test with.

Comment: Do you already have a headset you're trying to do this with? This seems like a technical support/info question, unless you are asking for a specific headset recommendation. (Make that clearer in your question if you are.) [Super User](https://superuser.com/) would be more appropriate for asking this question. Before you ask there, be sure to state which Bluetooth adapter you want to use a headset with; This *can* be done, but the adapter & drivers must support the bluetooth headset.